# rerender same component using useNavigate()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I am trying to rerender same component by using `useNavigate()` and passing `nanoid()` as different state in each click

```
<a
  href="#"
  className="theme-btn w-100 text-center margin-top-20px"
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate("/search", { state: nanoid() });
  }}
>
  Search Now
</a>
```

an intermediate component to render `CreateTopMenuResultPage`

```
export const RenderTopMenuResultPage = (props) => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const [rerender, setRerender] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    setRerender(state);
  }, [state]);

  return (
    <>
      {createPortal(
        <CreateTopMenuResultPage stateToPass={rerender}/>,
        document.getElementById('result-page-sort-menu')
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

and `CreateTopMenuResultPage` is

```
export const CreateTopMenuResultPage = (props) => {
  console.log("prop from renderTopMenu:::", props.stateToPass); 
  const [cardLoaded, setCardLoaded] = useState(false);   
  const [rerender, setRerender] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchCardData = async () => {
      try{..}
      catch (error) {     
        return { success: false };
      }
    }
    if (!cardLoaded) {
      fetchCardData().catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error occurred while fetching data:', error);
      });
    }
  }, [cardLoaded, props.stateToPass]);

  if (!cardLoaded) {
    return (..)
  }
  if (cardLoaded) {
    return (
      <>
        ...
        <p>{rerender}</p>
    );
  }
```

I see that each time I click `Search Now` `<p>{rerender}</p>` changes in UI but `fetchCardData` does not fetch data and nothing else changes in component. How can I make whole component rerender when clicking "Search Now"?

Comment: Where is `RenderTopMenuResultPage` rendered? Is `fetchCardData` called? I don't see where `fetchCardData` is actually called in the code you provided. Can you [edit] to include a complete [mcve]? Also, see if you can create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live.

Comment: Also, it's a bit of a React anti-pattern to store passed props and data into local state. `RenderTopMenuResultPage` should remove the `rerender` state and `useEffect` hook and just pass `location.state` directly through to `CreateTopMenuResultPage`'s `stateToPass` prop, e.g. `<CreateTopMenuResultPage stateToPass={state} />`.

Comment: @Drew Reese , thank you , I edited and included the logic and dependency  for `fetchCardData`   .  Also, for first render everything works fine. Trying to navigate to same route and rerendering does not work

Comment: My comment had a few other questions as well, and now I've a few more. Can you also clarify what "navigate to same route and rendering does not work" means exactly? You are already on `"/search"` and navigate to `"/search"` again but with different state? Is `RenderTopMenuResultPage` rendered on the `"/search"` route? Do you see `RenderTopMenuResultPage` rerender with the new state? Where does the logic break down and stop working as expected?

Comment: Yes , I am already on "/search"  and trying to navigate to "/search" again with different state.  Yes , in initial render `RenderTopMenuResultPage` has rendered on  "/search".   With new state , I only see `<p>{rerender}</p>` changed  in UI . By seeing  that , I am guessing that `RenderTopMenuResultPage` has rerendered but if it has then why data is not fetched

Comment: See if you can create a sandbox that reproduces the issue. Link is in my initial comment.

Comment: I will try to create. May be `cardLoaded` state is `true` from initial render and hence this part  `if (!cardLoaded) {
        fetchCardData().catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error occurred while fetching 
          data:',error);
        });`  never triggers on subsequent clicks . But I am not sure how to clear the state from initial render and set it to false . I tried setting `setCardLoaded(false)`  just above `const fetchCardData` and  inside `useEffect` and it keeps on sending request one after another in loop. How can I properly clear state after initial render?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the `setCardLoaded` to `false` in a separate useEffect like this and make the dependency as `rerender`

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setCardLoaded(false);
    console.log('setCardLoaded::: in useEffect', rerender)
  }, [rerender]);
```

and set `setRerender` to `props.stateToPass` like

```
export const CreateTopMenuResultPage = (props) => {
          console.log("prop from renderTopMenu:::", props.stateToPass); 
           const [cardLoaded, setCardLoaded] = useState(false);   
          const [rerender, setRerender] = useState('');
          useEffect(() => {
            setRerender(props.stateToPass);   //set rerender here
            const fetchCardData = async () => {
              try{..}
              catch (error) {     
                  return { success: false };
                }
             }
           if (!cardLoaded) {
               fetchCardData().catch((error) => {
               console.error('Error occurred while fetching 
               data:',error);
               });
            }
        }, [cardLoaded, props.stateToPass]);

   if (!cardLoaded) {
   return (..)
    }
        if (cardLoaded){
     return(
      <>
       ...
        <p>{rerender}</p>
        );
      }
```

it now routes to same route and fetches data on every click